# Wordpress: modifying archive with custom WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to create a custom category (archive) page for a specific set of categories, adding some querystring vars.

So, I have an url like http://example.com/services/restaurants?city=gotham

If I don't modify WP_Query I have a correct list of `services/restaurants` but I want to add a filter by city, so if I use WP_Query like this then I get all services (not only restaurants), so it's not working as expected.

This is my code:

```
<?php
$categories = explode("/", get_query_var('category_name'));

$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
                          'post_type' => 'services',
                          'category_and' => $categories,
                          'meta_query' => [['key' => 'city', 'value' => $_GET['city']]]
                        ) 
                      );

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php
endwhile;
```

This is **showing all services, not only restaurants** even `$categories` is an array with `[0] => 'restaurants'`.

**Note**: if I use SAVEQUERIES and print all `$wpdb->queries` I can see the correct queries are logged, but then, after this queries, other queries for all services are applied.

How can I use WP_Query to get the category marked by url and add my own meta keys?

Thank you.

Comment: You are not _modifying_ any query here, you are writing your own - those are very different things, in the WP philosophy. WP has one “main query”, that is responsible for loading the appropriate content for any type of page - so if you want other parts of your page, that come after this, work with your reduced set of posts - then you need to actually modify the main query, and not write your own, that is completely independent from the main query. The way to do that, is to hook into the filter `pre_get_posts`.

Comment: Does that change if I use variable `global $wp_query` instead of `$the_query`? In my tests it doesn't change

Comment: Where did you put this code? If this is in any template file, then the main query has already been executed, before it even gets to that point.

Comment: It's `archive.php` template

Answer (score 0):

Just use at top of your archive.php

```
if( isset( $_GET['city'] && ''!= $_GET['city'] ) {
    $city = $_GET['city'];
    global $query_string;
    $posts = query_posts($query_string."&meta_key=city&meta_value=$city");       
}
```

It will modify the original query and append it